# MySQL Case Sensitive Search Binary or Collate

Tags: mysql, binary, where-clause, collate

I need to do a case sensitive search on a field in my database. I see some people suggesting the Binary approach.

```
SELECT * FROM car WHERE BINARY brand = 'Toyota'
```

Others are using the Collate approach

```
SELECT * FROM car WHERE brand COLLATE latin1_general_cs = 'Toyota'
```

I'm not sure which one to use? What's the better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use utf8 characters binnary is best way to get case sensitive search.

Comment: Okay so I'm using Latin1 so I'll Collate.